# Dog walking "Heel"

Tags: usage, zoologie

It is common for dogs to be trained to slow down and stay closer to their owner using the keyword "heel". What word is used in the French language?

Comment: Is [that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Af17wIDud34) what you mean ? The action is *marcher au pied* and you say *au pied* to the dog. [In a dictionary](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/heel%20%5Bto%20a%20dog%5D)

Comment: @Laure Parfait! Merci!!!

Answer (score 3):

In French you say "Au pied !" which literally translates into English as "At my foot!".